# Error on makefile with threads and my library

Tags: makefile, static-libraries, gnu-make

So I have been searching and looking for something that could help me with the Makefile, but I did not find anything, so thats why I am here.

My makefile right now is like this:

```
CC  = gcc
CFLAGS  = -Wall
LDFLAGS += -L$(LIBB)
LDFLAGS += -static lib1.h
LDLIBS  = -lm -lpthread -lrt -l

SOURCES=lib1.c prac3.c prac3_reader.c
LIBRARIES=lib1.o
INCLUDES=lib1.h
PROGRAMS=prac3 prac3_reader

all: $(OBJS) $(PROGRAMS)

$(PROGRAMS): $(LIBRARIES) $(INCLUDES)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBRARIES) $(LDLIBS) $@.o -o $@


%.o: %.c $(INCLUDES)  
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  -o $@ -c $<

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ $(PROGRAMS)
```

I know there are probably a lot of things that can be removed, but I do not really know which ones are. I have two programs called

> prac3.c

and

> prac3_reader.c

Also, I have my own library called

> lib1.c

and also compiled like

> lib1.h

When I go to my directory with the terminal and use the command `make` I recive this error:

```
gcc -L -static lib1.h lib1.o -lm -lpthread -lrt -l prac3.o -o prac3
/usr/bin/ld: no se puede encontrar -lprac3.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'prac3' failed
make: *** [prac3] Error 1
```

I am running on Ubuntu.

Comment: What is the flag `-l` (without the name of a library) supposed to indicate?

Comment: which is why prac3.o is interpreted as a library and and not as a compiled object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-l` flag expects an argument. When it is combined in the `gcc` statement it causes the `prac3.o` argument to be considered as the name of a library. There is no such library `prac3.o`, so you get the error.

In general `.o` files aren't "libraries".  They are object files. Remove the `-l` flag and you will be fine.

"libraries" are generally `.a` or `.so` files from a library path - but even then, you wouldn't specify the suffix (.e.g "-lpthreads").

Comment: Thank you. I resolved with what you said, and now is like this:

`CC=gcc -pthread
CFLAGS=-c -g -Wall -std=c99
LDFLAGS=

SOURCES=lib1.c prac3.c prac3_reader.c
LIBRARIES=lib1.o
INCLUDES=lib1.h
PROGRAMS=prac3 prac3_reader
OBJS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)

all: $(OBJS) $(PROGRAMS)

#$(PROGRAMS): $(LIBRARIES) $(INCLUDES)
# $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBRARIES) $@.o -o $@

prac3: prac3.o $(LIBRARIES) $(INCLUDES)
 $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBRARIES) $< -o $@

prac3_reader: prac3_reader.o $(LIBRARIES) $(INCLUDES)
 $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBRARIES) $< -o $@

%.o: %.c $(INCLUDES) 
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<`

With the clean.